# Can't install AWS Elastic Beans CLI

Tags: python, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to host my django application on AWS EB but I can't install the cli for it.
Tried it both ways specified in the documentation but i got the same error every time.

```
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running egg_info
      writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\Documents\dev\peneszmentesites\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\Documents\dev\peneszmentesites\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\Documents\dev\peneszmentesites\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires 
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands   
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands   
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command    
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 314, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 322, in find_sources  
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 551, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults  
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 104, in add_defaults     
          super().add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "C:\Users\zsamb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cc9uz26d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__     
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried upgrading pip but it didn't help. And also, this only occurs for this package, i can install others.
I don't really understand the meaning of this error message, am i doing something wrong?
In the prerequisites it says that i need to have python, git and virtualenv installed and i have so in theory everything should just work:

Edit:
I also tried installing it from the virtualenv but got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue on my own. For anyone facing the same problem, here's how I resolved it:

Instead of using `pip install awsebcli`, I cloned the `awsebcli` repository from GitHub and installed it using `pip`. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Clone the `awsebcli` repository from GitHub:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup.git
   ```
2. Navigate to the cloned repository's directory:

   ```
   cd aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup
   ```
3. Install the `awsebcli` using `pip` with the dot `.` at the end to install from the current directory:

   ```
   pip install .
   ```

This approach worked for me and resolved the error I was encountering during the installation process. Feel free to give it a try if you're facing the same issue. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 2):

Issue relates to installation attempt of pre-release version of Cython. 
Refer the following link to understand more about the issue:
https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/601

Here is a workaround:

```
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 ./get-pip.py
sudo pip install "pyyaml<5.4"
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo pip install --upgrade pip awsebcli
```

You can find more info on workaround here:
https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/aws-elastic-beanstalk-orb/issues/31

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue while installing awsebcli.
The problem comes from pyyaml. It is somehow not compatible with the latest PEP.

The solution:
Manually install an old version of pyyaml.

```
pip install "pyyaml<5.4"
```

Then, run the command to install awsebcli.

```
pip install --upgrade pip awsebcli
```